# Error "'Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am learning React with this [tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/). And now I am dealing with the SignUp part. I am getting stuck here:
 should be in index.js of SignUp, but it is "moved" to context.js in Firebase. After that, I got error message as follow when I run the script:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Context.Consumer`.

It seems the error also related to index.js in src:

> ./src/index.js
>
> src/index.js:10

```
   7 | import App from './components/App';
   8 | import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase';
   9 | 
> 10 | ReactDOM.render(
  11 |   <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
  12 |     <App />
  13 |   </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
```

I am confused because I thought the FirebaseContext.Provider is defined in src/index.js and FirebaseContext.Consumer is moved to context.js of Firebase already? What is the problem here and how to fix it?

Thank you.

This is the index.js of SignUp:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import * as ROUTES from '../../constants/routes';

const SignUpPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>SignUp</h1>
      <SignUpForm />
      //<SignUpForm />
  </div>
);

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  username: '',
  email: '',
  passwordOne: '',
  passwordTwo: '',
  error: null,
};

class SignUpFormBase extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  onSubmit = event => {
    const { username, email, passwordOne } = this.state;

    this.props.firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
      .then(authUser => {
        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES.HOME);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });

    event.preventDefault();
  }

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      username,
      email,
      passwordOne,
      passwordTwo,
      error,
    } = this.state;

    const isInvalid =
          passwordOne !== passwordTwo ||
          passwordOne === '' ||
          email === '' ||
          username === '';

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
          name="username"
          value={username}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Full Name"
        />
        <input
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Email Address"
        />
        <input
          name="passwordOne"
          value={passwordOne}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Password"
        />
        <input
          name="passwordTwo"
          value={passwordTwo}
          onChange={this.onChange}
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
        />
        <button disabled={isInvalid} type="submit">Sign Up</button>

        {error && <p>{error.message}</p>}
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const SignUpLink = () => (
  <p>
    Don't have an account? <Link to={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>Sign Up</Link>
  </p>
);

const SignUpForm = withFirebase(SignUpFormBase);

export default SignUpPage;

export { SignUpForm, SignUpLink };
```

Here's the index.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import App from './components/App';
import Firebase, { FirebaseContext } from './components/Firebase';

ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
    <App />
  </FirebaseContext.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: `const SignUpForm = withRouter(withFirebase(SignUpFormBase));`, is withRouter call miss is causing the issue.

Comment: @tarzenchugh, thanks for the reply. I change from withFirebase(SignUpFormBase) to withRouter(withFirebase(SignUpFormBase)), but still showing the same error.